# Parameter Passing for statically included page in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, parameter-passing, ognl

I have a parent file where my JSP is statically included.

```
<%@include file="test.jsp" %>
```

In the included file I want to access the variable of parent JSP using Struts2 tag.

Please let me know if it is possible or should I go for *dynamic* include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the variable but you can access the variable from the the value stack using OGNL. See [OGNL Basics](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl-basics.html) to learn more about variables in Struts and how to use them.

> Besides the examples and descriptions given above, there are a few major changes in the EL since WebWork 1.x. The biggest one is that properties are no longer accessed with a forward slash `/` but with a dot `.`. Also, rather than using `..` to traverse down the stack, we now use `[n]` where n is some positive number. Lastly, in WebWork 1.x one could access special named objects (the request scope attributes to be exact) by using `@foo`, but now special variables are accessed using `#foo`. However, it is important to note that `#foo` does *not* access the request attributes. Because XWork is not built only for the web, there is no concept of "request attributes", and thus `#foo` is merely a request to another object in the `OgnlContext` other than the root.

To include JSP content dynamically use [`s:include`](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/include-tag.html) tag

> Include a servlet's output (result of servlet or a JSP page).
>
> Note: Any additional `params` supplied to the included page are not accessible within the rendered page through the `<s:property...>` tag since no valuestack will be created. You can, however, access them in a servlet via the `HttpServletRequest` object or from a JSP page via a scriptlet.
>
> **How To access parameters**
>
> Parameters are passed as request parameters, so use the `${param.ParamName}` notation to access them. Do not use the property tag to access parameters in included files.

```
<s:include value="test.jsp"/>
```

Comment: There are multiple parent jsp file that is using the test.jsp. Now for populating the common variable one is using expression tag while another is getting it from the request object (in two different Parent jsp). So, in that case, is it necessary to pass the value of the variable from parent jsp as parameter?

Comment: No, it's not. You can't pass parameters if you want this.

Comment: then how to go about it?

Comment: Also, it is not working with s:include, the included file is giving lot of error.

Comment: Could you post errors and please clarify your question, it's unclear what are you asking.

Comment: Solved the problem. In the parent page, I explicitly pushed the variable in the ValueStack. In the child page I retrived it using #variable_name

Comment: Did this answer helped you to do it?

Comment: yes, it did. It help me think of explicitly importing Value Stack and putting the variable in it. Thanks.

Comment: Great, then you can accept this answer because you can help others who have the same question to find a solution.